# как дважды повторить код python

Tags: python

к примеру код

```
i=0
i=i+1
print(i)
```

как его повторить два раза

Comment: Начинайте уже голосовать за какие-то ответы и отмечать их как подходящие. А то помогать вам желание у людей может пропасть. )

Comment: Может, уже книжку почитать про основы языка?

Answer (score 2):

Буквально повторить 2 раза:

```py
i=0
i=i+1
print(i)
i=0
i=i+1
print(i)
```

Или выделить в функцию и вызвать 2 раза:

```py
def func():
    i=0
    i=i+1
    print(i)

func()
func()
```

Но это буквально повтор кода 2 раза.
Если вам нужно 2 раза прибавить `1` к `i`, то так:

```py
i = 0
for _ in range(2):
    i += 1
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

Так?

```
i=0
for j in range(2): 
    i=i+1
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for j in range(2):
    i = 0
    i = i + 1
    print(i)
```

**Совет:** почитайте `PEP-8`, он есть на русском.

Answer (score 0):

```
count = 2
while count != 0:
    i=0
    i=i+1
    print(i)
    count -= 1
```

Переменяя сount - счетчик, значение которого будет обновляться после каждого исполнения кода.While - цикл, который будет повторяться пока не будет достигнуто условие для прекращения его работы.В данном случае интерпретатор выполнит код два раза.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]